# DSL Script `suppressFolderAutomaticTriggering` property isn't working

Tags: jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I wrote the following script to create jobs in Jenkins automatically.

According to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XK8ikOCpOw&ab_channel=CloudBeesTV) i can stop a build storm by adjusting the `suppressFolderAutomaticTriggering` property.

But when I run my script on Jenkins the property isn't honored.
Looking at the API docs, here: https://jenkins.company/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html#path/multibranchPipelineJob
I can see the option is there
(Check the screenshot below)
[image: multibranchPipelineJob properties]

The build storms are very annoying - so any help would be much appreciated!

Here is my script...

```
def credentialsID = 'xxx'
def repoOWNER = 'xxx'
def branchDiscoverPatternWithTags = "(PR-\\d.*|qat|master|^v\\d.*)"

[
[repo: 'xxx-styleguide'],
[repo: 'xxx-phonebook-sync'],
[repo: 'xxx-library-dpp']
].each { Map config ->
    multibranchPipelineJob("${config.repo}") {
        description "\n WDDs ${config.repo} project"
        displayName("${config.repo}".replace('-', ' '))
        branchSources {
            branchSource {
                source {
                    bitbucket {
                        credentialsId("${credentialsID}")
                        repoOwner("${repoOWNER}")
                        repository("${config.repo}")
                        traits {
                            headRegexFilter {
                                regex("${branchDiscoverPatternWithTags}")
                            }
                            bitbucketTagDiscovery()
                            bitbucketPullRequestDiscovery {
                                strategyId(2)
                            }
                            bitbucketBranchDiscovery {
                                strategyId(3)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        orphanedItemStrategy {
            discardOldItems {
                daysToKeep(1)
            }
        }
//The properties object is not working, so 'suppressFolderAutomaticTriggering' does't work causing a build storm
        properties {
            suppressFolderAutomaticTriggering {
                branches(".*")
                strategy("INDEXING")
            }
            }
        triggers {
            bitBucketMultibranchTrigger { }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with this too, as it seems like properties.suppressFolderAutomaticTriggering does nothing for multibranchPipelines.

There are however options for branchSources.branchSource.strategy;

```
multibranchPipelineJob('example') {
    ...
    branchSources {
        branchSource {
            ...
            strategy {
                allBranchesSame {
                    props {
                        suppressAutomaticTriggering {
                            strategy('NONE')
                            triggeredBranchesRegex('^$')
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
...
```